# Scala Function to return True/False when a date is present in a list

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a function where I would to pass a date as a String and would like to check if its previous date is present in a list that is passed as second parameter to the function. If yes then it should return a boolean.

```
def fn1(date: String, days: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
    ....
    ....

  }
```

Also, I need a similar function that extracts the day from the previous day of the input parameter and then looks it up in a list. This function also returns a boolean.

```
def fn2(date: String, days: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
        ....
        ....

      }
```

How can I implement this in Scala?

Comment: previous date mean just previous date or any previous date?

Comment: just previous date

Comment: 1) Why are you passing dates around as strings? 2) Converting strings to dates, computing previous dates, and checking whether something is in a list or not are three completely separate, orthogonal questions. Where exactly are you stuck? Do you not know how to convert string to date? Or how to compute the previous date? Or how to find something in a list? Please reduce the question only to the relevant part of your problem. Also, I don't see where you're "trying to create" anything, I see only empty method stubs with very unclear method names.

Comment: I know how to convert from string to date, but how can i get the previous date after parsing ? `def convertStringToDate(s: String): Date = {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    dateFormat.parse(s)
  }`

Comment: If you already know how to convert the strings to dates, then why don't you include it into your question. `SimpleDateFormat` is toxic legacy code anyway.

Comment: what do you suggest to use in place of SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: Hi @Arjun Can you also paste a sample input and a the output, so it will be easier for us to work on it. Thank you

Comment: @Arjun use `java.time`. Don't use `SimpleDateTime` and all the related cruft. See jwvh's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is confused and confusing. I don't understand the difference between `fn1()` and `fn2()`.

Still, maybe this will help.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def fn(date: String, days: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
  val dtFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("<expected format here>")

  days.contains(LocalDateTime.parse(date, dtFormat)
                             .minusDays(1)
                             .format(dtFormat))
}
```

Comment: If you are interested just in the Date part then you can user `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime`. Also I would just add that if your date is in format `"yyyy.MM.dd"` than you can just use `LocalDate::parse`, and you don't have to define a custom `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, your answer helped me to achieve what i wanted..I have updated the working code below

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't pass dates around as Strings, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
def fn1(date: LocalDate, days: Seq[LocalDate]): Boolean =
  days.contains(date.minusDays(1))
```

Comment: So short and consise can it be said. This is the best piece of advice in any of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can solve your problem. Based on your date format just change the `split("-")` delimiter.

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.Calendar
    object Driver{

      def getPreviousDate(date:String):String={
        val cal=Calendar.getInstance()
        val dateArr=date.split("-")
        val day=dateArr(0).trim.toInt
        val month=dateArr(1).trim.toInt
        val year=dateArr(2).trim.toInt
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day-1)
        val sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
        sdf.format(cal.getTime)
      }

      def fn1(date: String, days: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
       val prevDate=getPreviousDate(date)
       days.contains(prevDate)
      }

      def fn2(date: String, days: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
        val previousDate=getPreviousDate(date)
        val previousDay=previousDate.split("-")(0).trim.toInt
        val daysList=days.map(day=>day.split("-")(0).trim.toInt)
        daysList.contains(previousDay)
      }

      def main(arr:Array[String]) {
       val days=Seq("10-11-2018","11-11-2018","12-11-2018","13-11-2018")
        val date="15-11-2018"
        val status=fn1(date,days)
        println(status)
        val status2=fn1(date,days)
        println(status2)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think that your solution proposal does not handle the case if the first day of the month gets passed to the method.

Comment: I tested it and It is working fine for last date of month.

Comment: And it should work for the last date of the month, but I think it won't work for the first day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code, thanks to all for your help.

```
def isHoliday(date: String,
                       days: Seq[String],
                       holidays: List[String]): Boolean = {
    val dtFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val dayFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE")
    days.contains(LocalDate.parse(date, dtFormat).minusDays(1).format(dayFormat)) ||
      holidays.contains(LocalDate.parse(date, dtFormat).minusDays(1).format(dtFormat))
  }
```

** need to change the string dates to LocalDate.